# Saving each data.frame of list with write_xlsx

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse, purrr, rdata

Want to save each `data.frame` of a list separately as a `Excel Workbook` with `write_xlsx` function. Able to save each `data.frame` of a list separately as  `.RData` but not as `Excel Workbook`. Any thoughts.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)

df1 <- data.frame(X = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(X = 5:6)

ls1 <-
  list(df1, df2) %>% 
  set_names(c("df1", "df2"))
ls1
#> $df1
#>   X
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 
#> $df2
#>   X
#> 1 5
#> 2 6


map(.x = names(ls1), .f = function(x1){
  assign(x = x1, ls1[[x1]])
  save(list = x1, file = paste0(x1, ".RData"))
  })
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL


map(.x = names(ls1), .f = function(x1){
  assign(x = x1, ls1[[x1]])
  write_xlsx(x = x1, path = paste0(x1, ".xlsx"))
  })
#> Error in write_xlsx(x = x1, path = paste0(x1, ".xlsx")): Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
```

**Edited**

The following `R` code using `write.xlsx` function from `openxlsx` `R` package works and produces single `Workbook` with multiple sheets.

```
write.xlsx(x = ls1, file = "ls1.xlsx")
```

However, my requirement to save each data.frame in separate `Workbook` and tried the `write.xlsx` function from `openxlsx` `R` package which produces wrong output:

```
map(.x = names(ls1), .f = function(x1){
      assign(x = x1, ls1[[x1]])
      write.xlsx(x = x1, path = paste0(x1, ".xlsx"))
      })
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `writexl`, but I use the openxlsx package to do something like this. You create a workbook, then iterate over your list of data frames, writing each one to a sheet in the workbook. Is that basically what you're trying to do? The argument you have, `x1`, is a string, not a data frame. Why not just call `map` on `ls1`?

Comment: You can skip the assign function and just use" `write.xlsx(ls1[[x1]], path = paste0(x1, ".xlsx"))`

Comment: Use lapply in combination with write.xlsx to „loop“ through your dataframes and store wach one separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do:

```
library(openxlsx)
lapply(1:length(ls1), function(x) write.xlsx(ls1[[x]], file = paste0(names(ls1)[x], '.xlsx')))
```

The same code works exactly the same with `map`:

```
library(purrr)
map(.x = 1:length(ls1),
    .f = function(x) write.xlsx(ls1[[x]], file = paste0(names(ls1)[x], '.xlsx')))
```

Comment: Thanks @deschen for your answer. Wondering why the same code do not work with `map` command?

Comment: Not sure what does not work for you. See my update. It works exactly the same with map.